# Delete share method on linkedin api gives 403 error response

Tags: linkedin-api

The share was created on an organization profile with the same access token that now I'm trying to use to delete it. Accessing the share post is possible (GET method) but when trying to delete it (via DELETE method) it returns error 403 (Not enough permissions)

Method is documented at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-update-and-delete-api#delete

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets here, the delete method was later enabled: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api#delete

Now it works as expected